# How can I get the Boolean value from an ng-show attribute without re-evaluating the expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I am working on a project with lots of content dynamically shown / hidden using `ng-show`.  Some of the expressions being evaluated are verbose.  Something like this...

```
<div
  ng-show="some.object.with.nested.values
    && some.other.object.with.other.nested.values
    && also.looking.at.the.value.in.this.object
    && !obj.example.something.goes.here"
>...</div>
```

I need to make this content ADA WCAG 2.0 compliant.  As part of that effort I am adding `aria-disabled` attributes to all of the hidden content.  The `aria-disabled` attribute will have a `true` or `false` value.  So, if the content is hidden the `aria-disabled` attribute will be `true`, and if the content is visible it will be `false`.  In other words, it will always be the inverse of the `ng-show` value and it needs to update dynamically as the `ng-show` attribute's value changes.

For obvious reasons (E.g. maintainability, readability, bloat reduction, etc), I want to avoid duplicating the code and inverting each value with a bang, like this...

```
<div
  ng-show="some.object.with.nested.values
    && some.other.object.with.other.nested.values
    && also.looking.at.the.value.in.this.object
    && !obj.example.something.goes.here"
 aria-disabled="!some.object.with.nested.values
    && !some.other.object.with.other.nested.values
    && !also.looking.at.the.value.in.this.object
    && obj.example.something.goes.here"
>...</div>
```

I would prefer to do something like this...

```
<div
  ng-show="some.object.with.nested.values
    && some.other.object.with.other.nested.values
    && also.looking.at.the.value.in.this.object
    && !obj.example.something.goes.here"
 aria-disabled="{{invertNgShow(this)}}"
>...</div>
```

The idea is to use a custom `invertNgShow` function to get the Boolean value of the element's `ng-show` attribute, invert the value and return.  Needless to say, I do not have a working solution yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, I ended up creating a directive for this...

```
myApply.directive('ngAria', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false, 
    priority: 1000,
    link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {  
        elem.removeAttr("ng-aria");
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngShow, function(){
          elem.attr('aria-hidden', !scope.$eval(attrs.ngShow));  
        });
      }
    };
});
```

...and the HTML looks like this...

```
<div ng-show="some.object.value" ng-aria >...</div>
```

As you can see the directive takes the value of `ng-show`, inverts it, adds an `aria-hidden` attribute and applies the inverted `ng-show` value to the attribute.  Perfect, and far less markup.

Answer (score 1):

As ngShow accepts expressions. Just assign the calculated value to a variable and use it anywhere in the controller as below,

```
  v1: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="v1">
  v2: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="v2">
  v3: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="v3">
  ng-show: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="v123" disabled>
  <p ng-show="(v123 = (v1 && v2 && v3))" aria-disabled="{{!v123}}">Hello {{name}}!</p>
```

A Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/jg56QFsV6ohLu59EPS2H?p=preview